# how to get rid of security restriction error in odoo pos?

Tags: security, odoo, rules, odoo-12

i'am using multi company odoo 12 , and i have more then 8 companies each one has it's own POS , but most of them the get too much popup errors with different records while the cashier on the screen of the pos with  restriction rules and this the content of error "the requested operation can't be  due to the security restriction please contact your system administrator.

(document type: product, Operation: read)

(Records :[21343, 23423, 23434, ........], user: 9)

if i access the parent company and searched for the records i found it's belongs to another company , why this error appear and how can i get ride of it ?[image]

Comment: Active common product Catalog in General Settings under multi company

Comment: that's will let all companies see each other products and this not our scope